# Mysql select rows when selected value is found

Tags: mysql

This is the Create table statement

```
CREATE TABLE `numbers` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I have this table and trying to get some result but without success.
In the example above I have:

```
SELECT * FROM numbers where number <= 15
```

The ids = 10870 and 10885 indicates are higher than 15.

So I need to count how many rows are between the row 10870 (including this row) and 10885 (excluding this row).

In this case the result was 15, but this can occur many times in the whole rows, so I just need 7 times before now, the interval where number was higher than 15.

I'm trying like this but is not correct, maybe to use substring?

```
from (select number, count(id) as cnt
      from numbers where number > 15
      group by number
     ) t;
```

Also tried like this:

```
WITH n AS (
 SELECT id, number
 FROM (
  SELECT b.id, b.number, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY b.id ASC) r
  FROM numbers a
  JOIN numbers b ON a.id < b.id
  WHERE a.number > 15
 ) t
)
SELECT number, COUNT(id) counts
FROM n
GROUP BY number
```

PLEASE don't be rude and close my question if is not clear, just tell me and give me some time to change.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLDzn.png)

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what this means?
`The ids = 10870 and 10885 indicates are higher than 15.`

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. Those rows were filtered out because of a condition in your `WHERE` clause. Are there only ever two records that will meet that condition?

Comment: The only 15 I can see is that 10885 - 10870 == 15

Comment: @Thomas The table has always 1000 rows and can be more numbers from 15.01 or higher, so I need to count only the last 7 numbers higher than 15.

Comment: I suspect I still don't understand the question, because I think it's just `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers WHERE id BETWEEN 10870 AND 10885 AND number < 15`

Comment: @Barmar so, from all rows in the table, I need to find how many rows was between the last number > 15 and before the last one, from the last 7 times that occurred.

Comment: So the logic is find a row where number >15, find the next row where number >15 and count the number of rows between (if any)?

Comment: Note that in your picture, row 10884 is missing, so the correct answer is 14.

Comment: @jgritty it's just because row 10884 was 0.

Comment: @P.Salmon that's correct, count how many rows during the last 7 times when ocurred if any.  I've updated my question also. Thanks

Comment: Can you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE numbers` and update the result into your question?

Comment: Hey @FanoFN done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is what you're after:

```
SELECT n.* 
FROM numbers n 
JOIN
   ( SELECT 
           MIN(id) minid,
           MAX(id) maxid
       FROM numbers
      WHERE number > 15) v
 ON n.id >= v.minid
 AND n.id <= v.maxid
 WHERE number > 0
ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC
LIMIT 7;
```

Or perhaps if you just want what's in between and omit the last value where it's `>15` then you can just change

```
ON n.id >= v.minid
 AND n.id <= v.maxid
```

to

```
ON n.id > v.minid
 AND n.id < v.maxid
```

Or maybe with another column of `COUNT(*) OVER ()`:

```
SELECT n.*,
       COUNT(*) OVER ()
FROM numbers n JOIN
(SELECT 
      MIN(id) minid,
      MAX(id) maxid
FROM numbers
WHERE number > 15) v
ON n.id >= v.minid
AND n.id <= v.maxid
WHERE number > 0
ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC
LIMIT 7
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5faa778da6d7702f3719f78c0e95a1c9)

Comment: COUNT(*) OVER (): Worked well, but I believe you misunderstood. I need do this count for the last 7 intervals and not the last 7 rows. But thank you so much. Now I have something to start.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your data is representative of your problem so heres's my stab at what I think could be representative

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id int, val int);
insert into t values
(1, 10),(3, 15),(5,10),(6,15),
(7, 15),(8, 10),(9,10),(10,15),
(11,10),(12,10);
```

If you allocate a row number to all 15s and a roll number to all rows (just in case the id is not continuous) in 2 blocks (u and v) then you can join the 2 blocks and work out the row difference and then limit to restrict your result set.

```
select u.*, v.* ,rn2 - rn as rowsbetween 
from
(
select t.id tid,t.val tval,
         row_number() over (order by t.id desc) rn,
         s.id sid,s.val sval,s.rn15
from t
left join
(
select id,val,
         row_number() over (order by id desc) rn15
from t
where val = 15
) s on s.id = t.id
) u

join

(
select t.id tid2,t.val tval2,
         row_number() over (order by t.id desc) rn2,
         s.id sid2,s.val sval2,s.rn15 srn152
from t
left join
(
select id,val,
         row_number() over (order by id desc) rn15
from t
where val = 15
) s on s.id = t.id
) v
on v.srn152 = u.rn15 + 1
order by tid desc  limit 2;

+-----+------+----+------+------+------+------+-------+-----+------+-------+--------+-------------+
| tid | tval | rn | sid  | sval | rn15 | tid2 | tval2 | rn2 | sid2 | sval2 | srn152 | rowsbetween |
+-----+------+----+------+------+------+------+-------+-----+------+-------+--------+-------------+
|  10 |   15 |  3 |   10 |   15 |    1 |    7 |    15 |   6 |    7 |    15 |      2 |           3 |
|   7 |   15 |  6 |    7 |   15 |    2 |    6 |    15 |   7 |    6 |    15 |      3 |           1 |
+-----+------+----+------+------+------+------+-------+-----+------+-------+--------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

Your question does not clarify what your output should look like or whether 15 blocks are discrete - in my example rows 10-7 and 7-6 are considered